# What information for identification does a WiFi router get from a connecting device (Android)? What information can be spoofed?

Tags: network, wifi, anonymity, spoofing, mac-address

When I want my device to connect to a WiFi router and make the router not recognize the device I have to change the MAC and the hostname. Is this right? And what information will also be usually collected by a WiFi router? And how can I change the information my device is sending to the WiFi router to prevent my device from getting identified?

Comment: Note the second paragraph about Android 9:  https://source.android.com/devices/tech/connect/wifi-mac-randomization